# What does 真っ赤な in the example sentence referring to?

Tags: na-adjectives

I was playing some video game & I came across this sentence:

> スプラッタで真っ赤な、すりおろしリンゴが出てきそうで恐い

I want to ask what is 真っ赤な's role in this sentence, what does it describe?

I have an idea that it describes すりおろしリンゴ, but if that means "grated apples", then is "bright/deep red grate apples" a thing?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I have a hunch that this すりおろしリンゴ is a metaphor for something, but what's the context? Is this a horror scene?

Comment: @naruto It's just a person commenting on the fact that the other person can't cook.

Comment: That's an important context!

Answer (score 1):

> It's just a person commenting on the fact that the other person can't cook.

Okay, in that case, this sentence is simply a joke. Both スプラッタな and 真っ赤な are adjectives that refer to dreadful blood-soaked objects, so the speaker is making fun of the other person's personality as well as the cooking ability. Doesn't the cook have a personality related to this type of words (e.g., yandere or zombie-maniac)?